# JSON Schema for Expression Tree

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, jsonschema

I need to create schema for simple grammar expressions, where:

```
{Expression}:
     {Function}
     OR {Variable}
{Function}:   
     FunctionName [array of {Expression}]
{Variable}:
     VariableName
```

So I can write JSON tree expressions like this:

```
{
    "Expression": {
        "function": "MyFunc",
        "args": [ { "varName": "X1" }, { "varName": "X2" }, { "function": "MyFunc2", "args": [ { "varName": "123" } ] } ]
    }
}
```

I need to have ability of additionalProperties both for functions and variables.
Here is the schema that I created:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "var": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "varName": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": [ "varName" ]
        },
        "func": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "function": { "type": "string" },
                "args": { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/expr" } }
            },
            "required": [ "function" ]
        },
        "expr": {
            "oneOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/var" },
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/func" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Expression": { "$ref": "#/definitions/expr" }
    }
}
```

For some reason it does not pass validation, for expression above in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, showing the following errors:

> 1) The required property "varName" was not present
>
> 2) The value of property "Expression" must conform to exactly one of
>   the following schemas: {
>               "type": "object",
>               "properties": {
>                   "varName": { "type": "string" }
>               },
>               "required": [ "varName" ]
>           }, {
>               "type": "object",
>               "properties": {
>                   "function": { "type": "string" },
>                   "args": { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/expr" } }
>               },
>               "required": [ "function" ]
>           }

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is well written and without errors.  The problem must be in the validator you are using.  The schema validates successfully at both http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/# and http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/.  I also reviewed it in detail and found no errors.

One thing you can try is to use `anyOf` instead of `oneOf`.  It will produce the same result as `oneOf` because the two schemas are mutually exclusive.  If you are lucky, the bug is affecting `oneOf` but not `anyOf`.